# Using Finbuckle BasePathStrategy with a Blazor Server-side app doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a server-side app deploying in IIS under it's own website, for example `myproduct.contoso.com/MyApp` This is all working fine.

Now I want to add multitenancy using [BasePathStrategy](https://www.finbuckle.com/MultiTenant/Docs/Strategies#base-path-strategy) and [HostStrategy](https://www.finbuckle.com/MultiTenant/Docs/Strategies#host-strategy). So I set up the `appsettings.json` for multiple tenants. I also added the following to the `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddMultiTenant<MyTenantInfo>()
    .WithConfigurationStore()
    .WithHostStrategy()
    .WithBasePathStrategy();
```

and

```
app.UseMultiTenant();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{first_segment=}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});
```

As the `_Host.cshtml` is hit first when accessing the app, I added the following:

```
public PortalTenant Tenant { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    Tenant = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetMultiTenantContext<MyTenantInfo>()?.TenantInfo;
}
```

And as I want to access the tenant info in my razor components, I passed the `Tenant` property to `App.razor`:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <CascadingValue Value="@Tenant">
                <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
                    <Found Context="routeData">
                        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                            <NotAuthorized>
                                Not Authorized
                            </NotAuthorized>
                            <Authorizing>
                                Wait...
                            </Authorizing>
                        </AuthorizeRouteView>
                    </Found>
                    <NotFound>
                        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                            <p>Nothing here.</p>
                        </LayoutView>
                    </NotFound>
                </Router>
    </CascadingValue>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

So I deployed the app again and trying to access it using a tenant, eg. `https://myproduct.contoso.com/tenant1/MyApp`.

However, I get a 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ha! I am having the same issue with WithBasePathStrategy did you manage to work around it?

Comment: see this: https://github.com/Finbuckle/Finbuckle.MultiTenant/issues/501